# generating random integers between 0 and some value where half are in the set (0,5] and the other half (5,x]

Tags: java, random, numbers

I am looking for a way to generate a random integer from 0-x, where x is defined at runtime by the human user. However, half of those numbers must be greater than zero and less than or equal to 5 (0,5] and the other half must be in the set of [6,x].

I know that the following code will generate a number from 0-x. The main problem is ensuring that half of them will be in the set of (0,5]

```
    Math.random() * x;
```

I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, just looking for some hints. Thank you!

Comment: Just generate two sets, and shuffle the end result. If you're storing the result in a list, you can use Collections.shuffle()

Comment: Do you have a number specifying the size of the entire generated set, being that you want _half_ of it to be in (0,5], and the oher _half_ in the [6,x]?

Comment: no, I have no such set size since this is supposed to be used for a grocery line simulator. The "customers" arrive randomly between t=0 and t= simulation length. I have the customer arrival worked out, but this portion is to determine how many items are in their cart since half of them are shopping for at most 5 items, the rest are shopping for at least 6 items and at most x items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first flip a coin and based on that generate upper or lower number:

```
final Random rnd = new Random();
while (true)
  System.out.println(rnd.nextBoolean()? rnd.nextInt(6) : 6 + rnd.nextInt(x-5));
```

Or, using the unwieldy `Math.random()` (bound to have trouble at the edges of the range):

```
while (true)
  System.out.println(Math.floor(
     math.random() < 0.5 ? (Math.random() * 6) : (6 + (x-5) * Math.random())
  ));
```

Consider this as a hint only :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think he wants _exactly_ half, not probabilistically half.

Comment: @brian Usually in this context it is meant statistically half, but let's hear it from OP.

Comment: Can you explain what the `?` and the `:` mean?

Comment: Yes, I can. It is the conditional operator, also known as the ternary operator.

Comment: Yea, it is probabilistically half. However, we're supposed to use Math.random,not the Random class.

Comment: @user1642677 So you **do** want the complete code? OK, there it is. I suspect, however, it will have non-uniform distribution of numbers at the edges of the range.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the second one is a nice one-liner too! So sorry, I can't vote twice...

Comment: @ppeterka To be fair, it is surely broken :) I only vouch for the first solution.

Comment: Also, the other problem with that is that it'll return a number between 0 and x-5 if the ternary operation is false. I need it to return a value between 5 and x.

Comment: @user1642677 You tested it already? Wow, that's fast. I just don't get one thing: how can `x + (positive number)` result in less than x?

Comment: no, I didn't test it. Just read the code and that's what I read, but nevermind, I misread it. Didn't see the x+ when I read it

Comment: @user1642677 My code was wrong, but differently: the upper bound was 2x-5 instead of x because `x` should be replaced by `5`.

Comment: Yea, makes sense. Thanks. it's a very eloquent solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
 double halfX= x / 2.0;
double random = Math.random() * x; 
if( random< halfX ) {
    random = random*5.0/(halfX);
} else {
    random = (random/halfX - 1) * (x-5.0) + 5.0 ;
}
```

I think it is good now. This is less understandable and readable, but has only one call to random for each invocation. Apart from the fact MarkoTopolnic pointed out: the user needed an integer... I'd have to calculate what rounding would do to the distribution.

This is absolutely not easy... My head aches, so the best I can come up with:

```
double halfX= x / 2.0 + 1.0;
double random = Math.random() * (x+2.0); 
int randomInt;
if( random< halfX ) {
    randomInt = (int) (random*6.0/(halfX)); //truncating, means equal distribution from 0-5
} else {
    randomInt = (int) ((random/halfX - 1.0) * (x-5.0) + 6.0) ; //notice x-5.0, this range before truncation is actually from 6.0 to x+1.0, after truncating it gets to [6;x], as this is integer
}
```

The second part I'm not sure though... A few hours of sleep would get it right... I hope the intentions and logic is clear though...

Comment: Yes, tricky stuff this `Math.random()`... But we can leave at least **something** to OP to complete his homework :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I enjoyed this, and seen some fantastic ways one can code :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is curious, here's the solution I came up with based on Marko's solution.

I had the following class defined for another part of this program.

```
public class BooleanSource
{
private double probability;

BooleanSource(double p) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if(p < 0.0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Probability too small");
    if(p > 1.0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Probability too large");
    probability = p;
}

public boolean occurs()
{
    return (Math.random() < probability);
}
}
```

With that, I did the following

```
    private static void setNumItems(Customer c, int maxItems)
{
            BooleanSource numProb = new BooleanSource(0.5);
            int numItems;

            if(numProb.occurs())
            {
                double num = (Math.random()*4)+1;
                numItems = (int) Math.round(num);
            }
            else
            {
                double num = 5 + (maxItems-5)*Math.random();
                numItems = (int) Math.round(num);
            }

            c.setNumItems(numItems);
}
```